# Why is my C# object null after I have instantiated it? (Or have I not done that properly?)

Tags: c#, instantiation

Why is my C# object null after I have instantiated it?

I either don't know how to instantiate a class in C#, or there is a trick with 2D matrices that I'm missing here.  (Either way I'm new to it all, and I limit myself to asking one question on Stack Overflow per day, so go easy with the downvotes...)

My program is a Win8 app.

I have a C# class with three members.  They are:

```
class CMyClass
    {
        public double[][] matrix1;
        public double[][] matrix2;
        public double[][] matrix3;
    }
```

And I try to instantiate it in my program like this:

```
CMyClass myObject = new CMyClass();
```

Then if I try to access any of the matrix members to read or write to the arrays I get a null reference exception error that say the object isn't instantiated.  Is something missing from my class or is the problem with the way I try to instantiate the object?

Comment: You have not initialized the matrix variables.

Comment: In the constructor for CMyClass, you could assign something other than null to each matrix.

Comment: I see!  Thank you.   Am I supposed to do this inside the class constructor, or in the main program scope?  Also, does this mean I'm getting a null reference error for the class member and not the actual object?  

I should add that in the main program I did initialize matrix[0][0] to 0.0f before I tried to access that specific element.  I just didn't do it for every element in the matrix.

Comment: @OllieM Yes, the null reference exception would be referring to the matrices you're trying to access, not `myObject` itself.

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't instantiated those items yet.

```
class CMyClass
{
    public double[][] matrix1;
    public double[][] matrix2;
    public double[][] matrix3;

    public CMyClass()
    {
        matrix1 = new double[][] {};
        matrix2 = new double[][] {};
        matrix3 = new double[][] {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating an instance of an object initializes its members to their default values. For reference types (like an array) this means null.

You need to explicitly create an empty array of the size you want in the objects constructor;

```
matrix1 = new double[4][2];
```

you can also put it in the declaration of the member (but that would be odd since you probagbly dont know what size you want - or maybe you do)

Comment: This syntax doesn't seem to work in my constructor. 

 When I say matrix 1 = new double[4][2]; , the '[2]' is underlined in red and the suggested popup says "Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'.

Answer (score 1):

You have only instantiated the `CMyClass`, you haven't instantiated any of the members of the class.

Try adding a default constructor to the class, and in the constructor set the member values.

```
public CMyClass()
{
    matrix1 = new double[][] {};
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with tiny console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
      CMyClass myObject = new CMyClass();                 
      myObject.matrix1= new double[1][] ;
      myObject.matrix1[0] = new double[1];
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.matrix1[0][0]);     

      }
```

Comment: This works for me, thank you!

  Could you explain this syntax though?  I don't understand the placement of square brackets where you are creating new doubles i.e why does the second last line put [0] BEFORE "= new double[1];" ?

Comment: Oh wait I think I see.  So we add each new array of doubles to the matrix one by one?

Comment: I just added this for easy testing with just one element inside array. If you have more then you can create together. Here is nice reference for this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. This seems to be the best working solution for me:

```
> class CMyClass
> {
>     public double[][] matrix1; 
>         
>     public CMyClass(int x)
>     {
>     matrix1 = new double[x][];

>      for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
>      { matrix1[i] = new double[x]; }
>     }
> }
```

Then in program:

```
int matrixSize = 10;
CMyClass MyNewObject = new CMyClass(matrixSize);
```

Now I can read and write to the elements of the matrix.
Solved! =D